# How to mock controller dependencies while testing route from fakeApplication in playframework java

Tags: java, playframework

I am trying to invoke action method in the controller by creating the FakeApplication object and calling the route. This calls the action method in the controller. But the controller is dependent on few other objects. Now since I am not creating controller object, how can I mock those dependencies?

```
     Http.RequestBuilder request = Helpers.fakeRequest()
            .method(GET)
            .uri("/v1/test/someApple");

    Result result = route(fakeApp, request);
    assertNotEquals(NOT_FOUND, result.status());
```

Answer (score 1):

The Play documentation shows different ways to instantiate an Application for testing. To inject all members in a controller, you can use the GuiceApplicationBuilder.

```
@Inject Application application;
@Before
public void setup() {
  GuiceApplicationBuilder builder = new GuiceApplicationLoader()
      .builder(new Context(Environment.simple()));
  Guice.createInjector(builder.applicationModule()).injectMembers(this);
  Helpers.start(application);
}
```

For more information: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaFunctionalTest